# How to center the signals to start around zero

Tags: python, scipy, signals, signal-processing, sensors

I have been working with some sensor data and I came across each one and realised that some of the sensors do not start around zero. So, I was wondering is there a way to be able to move signals to the centre? See the image below for the signal plots and individual plots.

[image]

[image]

Example of one of the sensors can be found in this chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238608/signal)

Code:
(Get the signal)

```
for fp in DataPathList:
    k += 1
    # print(k)
    # Load spreadsheet:
    print('Opened file number: {}'.format(fp))
    dataset = np.loadtxt(fname=fp)
    y = dataset[:, column_no]
    y_signal[k] = np.array(y)
    y_S1_max_signal[k] = np.max(np.array(dataset[:, 0]))
    S_F = 1000
    N = np.array(y_signal[k]).shape[0]
    S_T = 1 / S_F
    t_n = S_T * N  # seconds of sampling
    x_time = np.linspace(0, t_n, N)
```

***Edit 1:***

I was able to solve this problem by subtracting the signal with its mean and managed to move the plot to start from 0. However, I have a question here will this cause a large change in my data?

```
for fp in DataPathList:
    k += 1
    # print(k)
    # Load spreadsheet:
    print('Opened file number: {}'.format(fp))
    dataset = np.loadtxt(fname=fp)
    y = dataset[:, column_no]
    y_signal[k] = np.array(y)
    y_signal[k] = np.array(y) - np.mean(np.array(y))
    y_S1_max_signal[k] = np.max(np.array(dataset[:, 0]))
    S_F = 1000
    N = np.array(y_signal[k]).shape[0]
    S_T = 1 / S_F
    t_n = S_T * N  # seconds of sampling
    x_time = np.linspace(0, t_n, N)
```

Comment: an example of input data and expected output would make answering this question a lot easier

Comment: @Marat Join the chatroom for the example file https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238608/signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to post code in order for people to be able to help you better. Generally, what you might want to do is centre your peak at 0. If you have a numpy array, use `np.argmax(array)` to find the location of your maximum. Then in matplotlib, make sure that you subtract that index from your xspace (the list/array that goes on your x-axis).

Comment: I am just using the data that I have. Find it in the chat here chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238608/signal

Comment: So, you mean I just normalise the array using the maximum amplitude?

Comment: @WDpad159, no *shift* using the index of the maximum amplitude

Comment: do you have an example of code? you can see the code of how I access the file and acquire the signal

Comment: Is it the same as this link (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55752/how-to-0-center-a-signal-that-fades/55754)